# Debugging crash in Cython code called from C++

Tags: c++, python-2.7, crash, cython

I'm working on the Opencog open-source framework's Python bindings trying to fix some crashes and I'm getting a crash in:

```
PyObject * pyAtomSpace;

if (atomspace)
    pyAtomSpace = py_atomspace(atomspace);
```

from:

https://github.com/opencog/opencog/blob/master/opencog/cython/PythonEval.cc#L148

where it crashes on the last line which calls into a cython routine that wraps the C++ object with a python object with the following cython code:

```
cdef api object py_atomspace(cAtomSpace *c_atomspace) with gil:
    cdef AtomSpace atomspace = AtomSpace_factory(c_atomspace)
    return atomspace
```

from: 
https://github.com/opencog/opencog/blob/master/opencog/cython/opencog/atomspace_details.pyx#L407-410

The crash is a SIGSEGV:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
#1  0x00007ffff6354b6f in opencog::PythonEval::getPyAtomspace (
    this=<optimized out>, atomspace=<optimized out>)
    at /home/opencog/src/opencog/opencog/cython/PythonEval.cc:160
#2  0x00007ffff6354dd7 in opencog::PythonEval::init (this=0x67eb60)
    at /home/opencog/src/opencog/opencog/cython/PythonEval.cc:103
#3  0x00007ffff635512e in opencog::PythonEval::instance (atomspace=0x62c300)
    at /home/opencog/src/opencog/opencog/cython/PythonEval.cc:226
#4  0x00007ffff7bb5a83 in opencog::CogServer::CogServer (this=0x62bd40)
    at /home/opencog/src/opencog/opencog/server/CogServer.cc:127
#5  0x00000000004141bb in TestCogServer::createInstance ()
    at /home/opencog/src/opencog/tests/cython/PythonModuleUTest.cxxtest:37
#6  0x00007ffff7bb2a4a in opencog::server (
    factoryFunction=0x4141a0 <TestCogServer::createInstance()>)
    at /home/opencog/src/opencog/opencog/server/BaseServer.cc:65
#7  0x0000000000416e51 in PythonModuleUTest::PythonModuleUTest (
    this=0x6216f0 <suite_PythonModuleUTest>)
    at /home/opencog/src/opencog/tests/cython/PythonModuleUTest.cxxtest:82
```

How do I debug this crash? I tried stepping in assembler. First I set a breakpoint on the line that's crashing with disassemble-next-line on. NOTE: I substituted `routine` for `opencog::PythonEval::getPyAtomspace(opencog::AtomSpace*)` below:

```
Breakpoint 1, opencog::PythonEval::getPyAtomspace (this=0x67eb50, 
    atomspace=0x62c2f0)
    at /home/opencog/src/opencog/opencog/cython/PythonEval.cc:160
160         pyAtomSpace = py_atomspace(atomspace);
=> 0x00007ffff6354b66 <routine+6>:  48 89 f7    mov    %rsi,%rdi
   0x00007ffff6354b69 <routine+9>:  ff 15 29 69 20 00   callq  *0x206929(%rip)        # 0x7ffff655b498 <_ZL40__pyx_f_7opencog_9atomspace_py_atomspace>
   0x00007ffff6354b6f <routine+15>: 48 89 c3    mov    %rax,%rbx
```

The registers before the callq:

```
(gdb) info registers
rax            0x1c 28
rbx            0x67eb50 6810448
rcx            0x7ffff7716320   140737344791328
rdx            0x68 104
rsi            0x62c2f0 6472432
rdi            0x67eb50 6810448
rbp            0x7fffffffe790   0x7fffffffe790
rsp            0x7fffffffe780   0x7fffffffe780
r8             0x0  0
r9             0x9b57b0 10180528
r10            0x7fffffffe550   140737488348496
r11            0x7ffff6354b60   140737324075872
r12            0x7ffff7b8b140   140737349464384
r13            0x0  0
r14            0x62c2f0 6472432
r15            0x62bf01 6471425
rip            0x7ffff6354b66   0x7ffff6354b66 <opencog::PythonEval::getPyAtomspace(opencog::AtomSpace*)+6>
eflags         0x206    [ PF IF ]
cs             0x33 51
ss             0x2b 43
ds             0x0  0
es             0x0  0
```

Which looks like the callq is a register relative call using the `%rip` register with a value of `0x7ffff6354b66` and an offset of `0x206929`.

```
(gdb) disas /r 0x7ffff6354b66+0x206929,+10
Dump of assembler code from 0x7ffff655b48f to 0x7ffff655b499:
   0x00007ffff655b48f <_ZN7opencog10PythonEval17singletonInstanceE+7>:  00 01   add    %al,(%rcx)
   0x00007ffff655b491 <_ZZN7opencog10PythonEval4initEvE19eval_already_inited+0>:    01 00   add    %eax,(%rax)
   0x00007ffff655b493:  00 00   add    %al,(%rax)
   0x00007ffff655b495:  00 00   add    %al,(%rax)
   0x00007ffff655b497:  00 00   add    %al,(%rax)
End of assembler dump.
```

and the raw memory dump:

```
(gdb) x/10 0x7ffff6354b66+0x206929
0x7ffff655b48f <_ZN7opencog10PythonEval17singletonInstanceE+7>: 0x00010100  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
0x7ffff655b49f <_ZL40__pyx_f_7opencog_9atomspace_py_atomspace+7>:   0x6213f000  0x00000000  0x6213f800  0x00000000
0x7ffff655b4af <_ZN5boost4asio5errorL17addrinfo_categoryE+7>:   0x62140000  0x00000000
```

Then single step with `si`:

```
(gdb) si
0x00007ffff6354b69  160         pyAtomSpace = py_atomspace(atomspace);
   0x00007ffff6354b66 <routine+6>:  48 89 f7    mov    %rsi,%rdi
=> 0x00007ffff6354b69 <routine+9>:  ff 15 29 69 20 00   callq  *0x206929(%rip)        # 0x7ffff655b498 <_ZL40__pyx_f_7opencog_9atomspace_py_atomspace>
   0x00007ffff6354b6f <routine+15>: 48 89 c3    mov    %rax,%rbx
(gdb) si
[2015-02-24 01:43:14:072] [INFO] PythonEval atomspace 1
0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
=> 0x0000000000000000:  Cannot access memory at address 0x0
```

I'm not sure where the zero dereference is coming from given all of the above, but I haven't ever been fluent with X86 assembler on linux.

It is acting like the cython code isn't getting linked properly when the dynamic library which contains it is loaded. Or something? Any idea why a call into the py_atomspace cython routine would result in this crash? Am I missing something obvious in the above? Or getting something wrong?

I should also mention that the above code works just fine in many cases, it has only been after I changed some of the ways in which Python is initialized that I got the above crash. So I'm trying to figure out how my changes could possibly have affected this call since I made no changes to either the cython code py_atomspace or the caller of py_atomspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that even though you need to initialize Python in one place, Cython must be initialized many places.

You need to call the Cython-generated import functions, in OpenCog's case:

```
import_opencog__atomspace();
```

and

```
import_opencog__agent_finder();
```

**in every single shared library** that calls a function declared in Cython code as "api". Otherwise, you get a crash on the first call to that function in that shared library. And as you can see above, the SIGSEGV doesn't leave a useful stack trace. It's just two assembly instructions and boom, the register relative callq segfaults. You know it's crashing in the api call, yes, but when you verify that you are indeed calling the import function, hell you just stepped through it, it still crashes. Calling it isn't enough, you need to have called it in that shared library.

And the Cython docs make no mention of this at all (at least until I submit my pull request to fix that).

Comment: Here's the updated Cython doc commit that adds a new paragraph in the section on calling Cython code from C:

https://github.com/cython/cython/commit/0efe7e4698c75059c42171e67c54fd54b503bf3e